# I have a Wordpress App with theme, I need a good newsletter plugin which lets me create popups, get forms to collect data, and send email notification

Tags: wordpress, forms, plugins, newsletter, modalpopup

So I have tried using the newsletter plugin with my good layers theme, but this plugin does not let me change the fields (I need to add phone number and name as a form requirement in addition to email address), I also need to be able to create a popup and for this plugin to notify the user once they have signed up on the webpage. If the plugin also stores the email addresses that would be perfect.

The plugin I have lets me collect users emails but it doesnt show anything on the page that the submission went through successfully,

Has anyone worked with a plugin like this that has popup capability, custom form fields, submission notification, and stores the user data before?

I was hoping to change or update the form fields on the newlsetter plugin I have and then I was going to try and use a different plugin for the popup/notification but Im not sure if the two plugins will be able to integrate with one another